# solvable leibniz algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

let $A$ be a leibniz algebra over an algebrically closed field $K$ of characteristic $0$.
I think if 
$A$ has basis $e_i$ ,$f_j$ , for $i=1,2,...,m$ and $j=1,2,...,n$, with $e_if_j=\lambda_{ij}f_j$, either $e_if_j=-f_je_i$, or $f_je_i=0$, and all other products between basis elements equal to $0$.
is solvable leibniz algebra.

is it true?
I want to this statement to levi theorem

thanks for help

Comment: Could you write a meaningful sentence? Is the question whether every Leibniz algebra possessing a basis with the prescribed property is solvable?

Comment: If all other products are zero then the square of every element is zero, which implies anti-commutativity in characteristic zero, so the second possibility doesn't occur unless the lambda's are zero. So A is a solvable Lie algebra.

Comment: @DavidTowers :thanks